# python base85 ascii85 encoding identification

Tags: python, regex, encryption, encoding

I have found a way to identify base64 encoding within strings, I am trying to identify if there is a plausable way to find base85/ascii85 encoding types so I can automate the decoding of them? I am using python 3.5. In my base64 check, I am using a regex match for a specified modulo 4. How might i find either base85 or ascii85 encoded data in a similar pattern? Below is my coded method for identifying base64 data. Thanks for your help.

```
import re
# Checks if data is base64 encoding


def is_base64(data):
    if len(data) % 4 == 0 and re.match('^[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]+\Z', data):
         return(True)
    else:
         return(False)
```

Comment: There are several base85 versions. Only one of them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85#btoa_version has an indentifiable marker.